# Как мне превратить пары чисел (str) в пары чисел (int)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например у меня есть:

```
lst = ['1,2' , '3,4' , '6,5']
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы стало:

```
lst = [[1,2] , [3,4] , [6,5]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = ['1,2' , '3,4' , '6,5']
newLst = [[int(j) for j in i.split(',')] for i in lst]
print(newLst)  # [[1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
lst = ['1,2' , '3,4' , '6,5']
new_list = []
for element in lst:
    data = element.split(',')
    print(data)
    nlst = []
    nlst.append(int(data[0]))
    nlst.append(int(data[1]))
    new_list.append(nlst)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['1,2', '3,4', '6,5']
newLst = [list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in lst]
print(newLst)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.